# Find and Replace (CTRL+H) script on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm looking for a "find and replace" script for Google Sheets.

I have phone numbers on column `C`, which are in a `###-#######` format.

I want to make a script that will replace the "-" to nothing.

Then it will be: `##########`.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1**: Using `Find and Replace`

Select `C` column or the range where you want to find and replace.
Then `CTRL+H` for Windows or `CMD+H` on MacOs

In `Find`: -

In `Replace`: Nothing

Then click on `Replace all`.

[image: Search]

**Method 2**: Using a formula

You can also use `=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(C:c,"-",))`  on cell `D1` for example to obtain a column with phone numbers without `-` .

### Edit

**Method 3**: Using Apps script

```
  // I need to replace more occurrences of different strings, so this is just an example..
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("C:C1000").getValues();

  // this is a loop, to go through multiple cells that may contain the text, that needs to be replaced.
    for (var i = 0 ; i<range.length ; i++) {
        var le = range.length;
        var stri = range[i].toString().replace("-", "");
        Logger.log(stri);
  }  

  var msg = ui.alert("Replaced?");
  return msg;
```

Credit goes to Alex's answer [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51261373/11874533)

Comment: Thanks for the edit marikamitsos, I really need to improve my editing and poor english skills haha

Comment: Is there more ressources about formating ? I didn't find instructions/guides except for https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting // I'm looking for shortcuts, tips, or some templates. (I was looking at old answers until now for references)